# Excel VBA multiply multiple rows each by their own number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the best way to multiply a row of data by a variable.  I have a table like this:

[image]

I have a script that asks me to enter the number of the days the analyst worked during that time period.

What I want to have happen next, is another table with the same header and formatting be filled in with the above data divided by the days worked.   I.E. let's say the first row under Staff Time, 24:54:55 divided by 3 days worked, so 8 hours and change.

I want this to all be in the code, as opposed to functions in the excel sheet.

I tried using a function like:

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("G54:R54")
    rng = (rng / wd1)
Next rng
```

But that did not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Look into PasteSpecial divide

Comment: Scott's suggestion can be implemented within your current coding.

Comment: Or you can use Evaluate with an array formula: `[G54:R54]=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(G54:R54/" & wd1 & ",)")`

Comment: So if I wanted to paste the new values in G54:R54, but I am multiplying (number of days worked) by the values in G44:R44, would it then be [G54:R54]=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(GR4:RR4/" & wd1 & ",)")

Comment: If neither of those options work then your time is not a true time but text that looks like time.  You will need to convert the text to time by parsing the string into its parts using Left,Right, and Mid and putting the parts into `TIMESERIAL()`

Comment: Now that I think on it, what do you mean by it does not work?  You get an error?  You get the wrong output?  Please explain in more detail what you mean by it does not work.  There are a myriad of possible problems and answers to each.

Comment: Well, using the code I posted in the OP, I get an Overflow Error 6.  I am testing the code you provided to me now.

Comment: Declare wd1 as a double not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wd1? Did you declare it? If not, it is zero, hence a divide by zero error.
Otherwise code is fine & works on my computer.

Use option explicit to avoid such mistakes.

Edited: calculating for example 380*1000/60  does raise an error because all those are assumed to be integers. Maybe it can be related, try using cdbl(rng)

Comment: Sorry, it is declared.  In this case, wd1 corresponds to a specific analysts total number of days worked that week.

Comment: @sbagnato : what's wrong then? Maybe the range contains a string? Maybe adding .value2 to the ranges would help too... What's the error message?

Comment: strange... are you sure WD1 is non null? Or even not almost null?

Comment: @sbagnato  : try forcing the conversion todouble with cdbl, it might solve it

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following in the past (dynamic range, pastes to Sheet2 in the same location):

```
Sub Paste_Special_Divide()

Dim LR As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim MsgBoxy As Integer
Dim Source As Range
Dim Destination As Range


LR = Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set Source = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O" & LR)
Set Destination = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:O" & LR)

MsgBoxy = Application.InputBox("Enter selection divisor:", Title:="Selection divisor", Default:=10, Type:=1)

Source.Copy
Destination.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Hopefully that helps!